# Calculating log-likelihood or BIC of KNN and random forest/boosting models

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, random-forest, boosting, k-nearest-neighbour

I am trying to find the BIC of the KNN, random forest and boosting models (for regression, not classification) to use in a combined model that uses Bayesian model averaging to predict a target variable. (Reference: https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics15.pdf).

Since the BIC involves the log-likelihood value, is this even possible? If not, how else can I combine the predictions of these nonparametric models to possibly achieve a higher accuracy (in terms of mean squared loss when the combined model is used to classify a test data-set?)